# getting http 400 bad request spring mvc

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I am working on  Spring mvc project.

I have to implement rest apis, one api which i am implementing now return http 400 bad request. in it get method request. another api working properly for same json but this api returns HTTP 400

controller function

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getSlotsByDateRange/hosid/{hos_id}/from/{start_date}/to/{end_date}" , method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<SlotByDateRange> getSlotsByDateRange(@PathVariable String hos_id,@PathVariable String start_date,@PathVariable String end_date) {
        return new ResponseEntity<SlotByDateRange>(hospitalService.getSlotsByDateRange(hos_id,start_date,end_date),HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
```

Request url:

> getSlotsByDateRange/hosid/0009/from/2021-04-15/to/2021-04-22

Comment: You need to specify attribute `method = GET` to your `@RequestMapping` annotation or should use `@GetMapping`.

Comment: @code_mechanic  it is available

Comment: I missed that apologies.

Comment: can you post the controller class? you can remove other methods.

Comment: @code_mechanic same issue. issue with from and two params , if send without one of those api is working

Comment: How are you calling this URL from Postman?

Comment: @code_mechanic yes

Comment: Try calling the URL by url encoding it.

Comment: What if you change path variables like that: @PathVariable("hos_id") String hos_id. Would that work?

Comment: @photeesh that  is  working

Answer (score 0):

I have just implemented it and it is working for me.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getSlotsByDateRange/hosid/{hos_id}/from/{start_date}/to/{end_date}" , produces = "application/json")
```

For get requests you can use @GetMapping instead of @RequestMapping.  As @GetMapping itself contains

```
@RequestMapping(
    method = {RequestMethod.GET}
)
```

Hope this helps someone else as well.